# How to convert a number to words in MS Excel Android app automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel macros are unsupported in Android and there is also no SpellNum function. I want a function which can convert a number to words.

Also, I am unable to find any relevant ways of doing so in the Google Sheets Android app.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: I asked this on Super user , but it is migrated to this site , thats why it appear duplicate , keep this closed